# Animations are laggy on KitKat but smooth on Lollipop and up

Tags: java, android

I'm animating the movement of multiple views like this (basically just using y positioning):

```
View.animate()
    .setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
    .y(requiredCalculatedPosition)
    .setDuration(400);
```

But the snippet has visible lags in KitKat and below while running buttery smooth on Lollipop+. (Only tested on emulators till now, with graphics managed by my GPU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android literally sucks when it comes to animating multiple UI views **simultaneously** in pre Lollipop versions. I managed to make things smoother by adding little delays in my animations, but I was unable to get rid of total animation flicker when animating more than one view. Also another thing - it also depends on device, usually flickering would appear in cheap devices with weak GPU like Acer or Asus tablets or so due to their GPU limitations. Generally it will work well in most devices like older Samsung Galaxy S2, S3. Also emulators can't emulate GPU well - this is a thing I find always disappointing compared to iOS emulators.

Comment: Thanks! Should I set a delay using `.setStartDelay()`? Also can a few milliseconds be enough?